# Betrayal at House on the Hill scenario where a hero dies after using a haunt-related item

Tags: betrayal-at-house-on-the-hill

If I have successfully used the ring to perform an exorcism (one of multiple required) and later that hero dies, does the exorcism still count? Or, does the successful attempt die with character who was holding the ring when he died?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### In general, the heroes work toward a communal goal with a communal pool of successes.

I can't comment on the specific haunt you were playing, because I am not familiar with it, but as a general rule the successes that a hero achieves are shared, and the death of a hero does not invalidate the progress they made.

Comment: ...unless specifically mentioned. There are a few but I don't think this is one.